# Kernel as a line formed by the intersection of two planes???

Tags: linear-algebra

May I ask you to explain to me how did they arrive to idea that in order to describe kernel we need to describe the intersection of lines? Why does kernel an intersection of lines? Kernel is the set of the solutions that yield Ax = {0} as I see it.
The way I approached it was to write Kernel = [v1, v2, v3][-1,1,2] = [-v1 + v2 + 2v3]. Therefore -v1+v2+2v3 = 0.
We can express vector v3 in terms of v1 and v2 and then substitute any numbers for v1 and v2 to get v3. 
Thank you.

[Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WXD91.png)

[Solution to the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/70qgf.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the equations,

$$x+y = 0$$
$$2x+z = 0$$

You can write this as,

$$\underbrace{\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 2 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}}_{A}\begin{bmatrix}x \\ y \\ z \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$$

Associating $A$ to the linear map $T: \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^2$, then the solutions set is the set of points $(x,y,z)$ such that $T(x) = Ax = \vec{0}$. Geometrically one sees that two plane intersect at a line . The vector parametrization for that line is given by $\vec{r}(t) = \vec{p_0}+t \cdot (\vec{n_1} \times \vec{n_2})$ where $\vec{p_0}$ is the position vector for the point in the intersection and $\vec{n_i}$ correspond to the normal vectors of the planes.

Comment: Thank you Faraad. But why the kernel is an intersection of lines? Does it always like that? Also, how did they come up with that solution? I don't see it.

Comment: The kernel is the intersection of the two planes. And no, of course not. Which solution? The matrix? Do the matrix multiplication and see what you get.

Comment: They say: "To describe the subset of R^3 as a kernel means to describe it as an intersection of planes"!!!! How did they arrive to this statement? Then they say: "By inspection the given line is the intersection of:... " What inspection did they do? Thanks

Comment: The subset of they are referring to is the intersections of the plane. To describe it as a kernel, which I did above then it is the solution set to the linear system i.e an intersection of the two plane equations.